# AngularJS and Ionic: 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

Hello, I got this problem on iOS 9 on switching the screens. Why can this be cause? I can't even imagine why this happens. Please, comment if you need some code.

Comment: Do you have anymore information as to where the error is thrown? Ive only seen it once and the error pointed to the expression causing it. In my case it was a filter on an array modifying the original array causing the filter to be run again which modified the array and the loop continued.

Comment: Why this happens is explained quite well in the [AngularJS documentation about the "Infinite $digest loop" error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig). Where this happens in your application and how it can be fixed though, is more difficult to say, without any code provided by you.

Comment: It is really so strange, because I got this error on iOS device, not in the browser (from ionic serve command)

Comment: Also, I get this error: [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (photo{{$index % 5 + 1}}.png, line 0)

I am using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts in this app